# Java int cast to float cast to int does not equal original int

Tags: java, math, floating-point

Using this snippet:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = XXX;
        System.out.println( (int) ( (float) i ) );
    }
```

If `int i = 1234;` then the output is `1234`

If `int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` then the output is equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

However, if `int i = 1234567990;`, then the output is `1234567936`, which is not equal to `i`.

And if `int i = 1235567990;`, then the output is `1235568000`, which is also not equal to `i`.

How does this casting conversion math work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is entirely normal for floating point maths. Both `int` and `float` are 32-bit values. `float` only has about 7 significant digits of precision, because it uses some of the bits for scale. As you get to large values, "adjacent" `float` values (i.e. going from one precisely-representable value to the next one up) are more than 1 apart - so any integer between those two adjacent values *can't* be represented precisely as a `float`.

Another way of looking at this is a version of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle):

- Both `float` and `int` have 2^32 possible bit patterns
- There's a valid mapping from every `int` to a `float` value
- *Every* bit pattern is a valid `int`, so there are 2^32 possible integer values
- `float` also contains the value 1.5 (and many other non-integers, but we only need one of them to prove the point)
- Therefore *at least two* `int` values must map to the same `float`, which means the mapping *cannot* be reversible in every case

Note that if you use `double`, you're fine - every `int` can be cast to `double` and then cast back to `int`, and you'll get the original value. However, using `double` and `long` (instead of `int`) you get the same problem, for the same reason, but using 64 bits instead of 32.

Answer (score 0):

> How does this casting conversion math work?

Casting an `int` to a `float` works the same way any float operation works: Do the math (which in this case is nothing - just take the int as is), then convert it to the 'nearest representable float' - that float which is closer to the result of the calculation than any other.

Why is it 'lossy'? See the other answer.

What's the math behind which floats are representable? [Wikipedia's page on IEEE754 floating point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) explains that.